# SWT table filter with special characters

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

Hi I am adding a column level filter to a tableviewer, which will have special characters in the column being filtered. That column will contain xpath string as data, which obviously will contain special characters like the below,

**xpath=//a[@name='panels:swappableContent:toggleButton']/span[@class='standardized-icon expandIcon']**

I have created a filter object, code is given below,

```
public class ObjectLocatorFilter extends ViewerFilter {

    private String searchString;

    public void setSearchText(String string) {
        // ensure that the value can be used for matching
        this.searchString = ".*" + string + ".*";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean select(Viewer viewer, Object parentElement, Object element) {

        if(searchString == null || searchString.length() == 0){
            return true;
        }

        Element elem = (Element) element;

        if(elem.getObjectLocator().matches(searchString)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and added the filter to the table viewer, using the below code,

```
objectLocatorFilter = new ObjectLocatorFilter();                
tableViewerPageObjects.addFilter(objectLocatorFilter);
tableViewerPageObjects.refresh();
```

but when tried to search with text like [@class='', it results with below exception,

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 13
.*[@class=''.*
         ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)
```

Pls guide me on how to add resolve this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression when you seem to just be wanting to match an exact string? What is `Element`? Note that TableViewer is JFace not SWT, but this seems to be more of a Java question.

Comment: the filter applied column will have similar xpath strings, out of which, i just need to filter the required one, so I need to pass a partial string which some of the column strings may contain.Yes this is of JFace and java, not SWT.

Comment: As in my answer you don't need a regular expression to test for one string containing another string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `Pattern` to handle special characters in your search string you must `quote` it:

```
this.searchString = ".*" + Pattern.quote(string) + ".*";
```

But since you are just looking for the search string in the element you don't really need a regular expression at all. Just use the `contains` method of `String`:

```
if (stringToSearch.contains(stringToFind)) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: this is truly helpful and it resolved my requirement. thanks a lot @greg-449.